# Visa requirements for transit through Panama

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, panama

I am an Indian national with a valid visa for Costa Rica. Do I need a visa to transit through Panama?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=cr&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=pa&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit of 12 hours, or until
>   the first connecting flight [to your next destination]

So no, you do **not** need any transit visas